# Microsoft Store API : Cannot create promo code for addon type 'Subscription'

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to simulate purchase for a subscription addon.  Its a free addon but still purchase process flow **force** asks me to enter Creditcard or paypal details. (was not expecting this)

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295970/simulate-purchase-with-windows-services-store-addons) that one can create promo code to test the purchase process without feeding money.   The promocode generation page displays all addons except of type 'Subscription'.

***Q1. So question is how to i generate promocodes for a subscription type of addon ?***

There is next question in pipeline related to same. I created promocode for a consumable addon now how do i use it ?   There is only option gift card and when i paste promocode it show error as attached in screenshot.

***So Q2. Even if i successfully create promocode, how and where i can use it during purchase flow. ?***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not possible** to generate promotional codes for subscription add-ons. This is mentioned on the document - [Generate promotional codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/generate-promotional-codes#promotional-code-policies) : *You can generate promotional codes for any app or add-on (**with the exception of subscription add-ons**) that you published to the Microsoft Store.*

So you can't use such a way to test the purchase subscription.

A possible way for testing purposes is that you could create a test subscription add-on that is free to purchase. Then you could purchase it to check the purchase process. After you go through the whole purchase process and make sure everything is correct, you could do the same to the real subscription add-on.

Comment: If one creates a 'promotional code' for a consumable addon, where does one apply that code?  Because as Neha said the purchase process only has an option of 'gift card' and it does NOT accept 'promotional codes.'

Comment: Hi Roy,  Need more help on the topic...  (we are trying to purchase addon from MSFT Store Sample, as seen in screenshot,  Sample app is associated with one of our app in store, and it does list, list of addon from that app correctly )  I & my team tried entering credit card to complete the purchase flow.. but in the end we get an error, "the region in which your payment option was issued and your store region need to match".      can you please advise on this...

Comment: @Neha Please check if your payment method has a different region than the region you choose in your Microsoft store. If your credit card registered address is in Brazil and your Microsoft Store region is USA you should change the region of the Microsoft Store to Brazil. Besides, it's not a development quesiton.

Comment: Found the answer :  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/change-your-country-or-region-in-microsoft-store-5895e006-34f4-10f7-16b1-999e40adb048